# How to join without foreign key constraint in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a situation where it would make a lot of sense to have a couple of generic foreign keys. That is, columns that contain the ID of another table without defining foreign key constraints.

In the code below, the `Transfer.FromId` and `Transfer.ToId` contain the IDs of another table. The exact table is determined by the `Transfer.FromType` and `Transfer.ToType` columns.

```cs
public enum TransferType
{
    Ship,    // FK to Ships table
    Railcar, // FK to Railcars table
    Truck,   // FK to Trucks table
}

public class Transfer
{
    public TransferType FromType { get; set; }
    public int FromId { get; set; }
    public TransferType ToType { get; set; }
    public int ToId { get; set; }

    public DateTime TimeStamp { get; set; }
    public double Quantity { get; set; }
}
```

To find all the railcars that were loaded into a specific truck, for example, I might write SQL similar to this.

```sql
select t.*
from Transfers t
join Railcars r on t.ToType = 2 
                and t.ToId = truckId 
                and t.FromType = 1 
                and r.Id = truckId
```

But how would I write something similar in Entity Framework? It seems like I would require separate queries to first get the Railcar IDs, and then get the actual Railcars. Are there any techniques for this that I don't know about?

Comment: Most of that should just be moved into a where statement.  All that's needed in the join is `r.Id = t.ToId`

Comment: @juharr: Yes, I can filter for the `Transfers` I want. But that doesn't get me the `Railcars` details without a join.

Comment: You'd just select whatever columns you need from both tables.

Comment: @juharr depends. Sometimes Performance can vary based on where you place your join constraints

Comment: @juharr: That's what I'm asking.

Answer (score 1):

It is simple quuery:

```cs
var query = 
    from t in ctx.Transfers
    where t.ToId == truckId && t.ToType = TransferType.Truck && t.FromType = TransferType.Railcar
    from r in ctx.Railcars.Where(r => r.Id = truckId)
    select new 
    {
        Transfer = t,
        Railcar = r
    };
```

Comment: I can try this. The assignment to `Railcars` would use `First()/FirstOrDefault()` instead of `ToList()`.

Comment: Better update question with desired destination class. From question i see that you need all Railcars.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, the way you have it, I will get a list of railcars for each transfer. Since transfer has the railcar ID, there can only be one railcar per transfer. I do want all the railcars, but only one per transfer.

Answer (score 0):

Based on other feedback, I found I could simply do the following.

```cs
var query = dbContext.Transfers
    .Where(t => t.ToId == truckId && t.ToType == TransferType.Truck && t.FromType == TransferType.Railcar)
    .Select(t => new
    {
        Railcar = dbContext.Railcars
            .Where(r => r.Id == t.FromId)
            .First(),
        t.TimeStamp,
        t.Quantity,
    });
```

Aside from testing the transfer types, it seems like this should perform close to if I had a foreign key constraint. Of course, here, I need to concern myself with the fact that it's possible I'll have a railcar ID but the railcar no longer exists.

I don't think this can be improved on but would love to hear about it if someone thinks it could.